# Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine' with Exporter class from GitHub

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a tool I found here: https://github.com/ignatandrei/Exporter

This should take an IEnumerable and generate a Byte[] value of Excel, Word, or PDF. I am using Mvc 5.2.3.0

I’m trying to use these classes:

```
public abstract class ReportBase : IReport
{
    virtual public string ReportName { get; set; }
    virtual public ICollection<IReportSection> ReportSections { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ReportSectionBase : IReportSection
{
    public string ReportSectionName { get; set; }
    public ICollection ReportItems { get; set; }
}
```

And in my controller I am trying to do this:

```
public virtual ActionResult processReport()
{
    if (Session["reportData"] != null)
    {
        var report = Session["reportData"] as ReportBase;

        // Error here
        Export<ReportBase> export = new ExportExcel2007<ReportBase>();

        var data = export.ExportResult(new List<ReportBase>() {report});
        return new DownloadFileActionResult(data, "test.xlsx");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the error I get:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.7.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9ee697374c7e744a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 3232:                var report = Session["reportData"] as ReportBase;
>   Line 3233:
>   Line 3234:                Export export = new ExportExcel2007();
>   Line 3235:
>   Line 3236:                var data = export.ExportResult(new List() {report});
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem\Controllers\ProjectController.cs    Line: 3234

I'm having a rough day, not feeling well, and can't seem to get things to work.

Comment: It looks like your application requires assembly RazorEngine version 3.7.6.0 and cannot find one.

Comment: Or was found, but in a different version that the required. Assert to use the same version of the RazorEngine than the tool uses

Comment: I have 3.7.0.0. Can I update that through Nuget?

Comment: open the package console and write: `uninstall-package RazorEngine`, and after `install-package RazorEngine  -Version 3.7.0.0`